# Oracle SELECT - question about performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

There is a table:

```
key1, fkey1, option, symbol
1     5      'A'     1
2     6      'B'     1
3     7      'C'     1
4     8      'D'     2
```

Let's say I have data of record `key1=2`. This row has a `symbol = 1`, so my goal is to get all rows (especially values of column `fkey1`) where `symbol = 1` (desired output here: `fkey = 5,6,7`).

**Question:** Can this be done in one `select` query, and querying this table ONLY once(!)? Not like:

`SELECT fkey1 from table where symbol = (select symbol from table where key = 2)`

I'm looking for a way to optimize it to the maximum. This table in reality has more columns and PK/FK consist of few columns.

Comment: I think your way of doing it, is the fastest possible. The subselect `(select symbol from table where key = 2)` is done using a unique index scan and only gets one result and then the outer select is done using a normal index scan. Just make sure you have suitable indexes - there should be one on "symbol,fkey1,..." to optimize performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with only a single query and no self-joins. Use an analytic function over the entire table to find the matching symbol:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( key1, fkey1, "option", symbol ) AS
SELECT 1, 5, 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 6, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 7, 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 8, 'D', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX( CASE key1 WHEN 2 THEN symbol END ) OVER () AS symbol_to_match
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  symbol = symbol_to_match
```

**Output**:

```
KEY1 | FKEY1 | option | SYMBOL | SYMBOL_TO_MATCH
---: | ----: | :----- | -----: | --------------:
   1 |     5 | A      |      1 |               1
   2 |     6 | B      |      1 |               1
   3 |     7 | C      |      1 |               1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e9562df038a2ff3d566b541acb173de3)*

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid subquery but need you need  a join with the same the table two time

```
select  a.fkey1 
from table a 
inner join table b  on a.symbol = b.symbol  and b.fkey1 = 2
```

with proper index  on symbol or a composite index  on symbole and fkey1 the performace should be good